# How to create a new repository with PyGithub

Tags: python, git, github

How can I create a new repository with PyGithub on Github? 
In particular I like to know how to use the [`create_repo`](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/AuthenticatedUser.html?highlight=create_repo#github.AuthenticatedUser.AuthenticatedUser.create_repo) method? How do I generate a `AuthenticatedUser`?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new git repository locally?  Or a new repository on github?  `PyGithub` does the latter, while something like `pygit` does the former.  Both seem to be well documented online.

Comment: I am trying to create a repository on Github.

Comment: @larsks Could you please give an example on how to create with PyGithub a repository on GitHub?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution to my question is the following

```
g = Github(token)
user = g.get_user()
repo = user.create_repo(full_name)
```

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled across this question trying to figure out how to coax PyGithub into creating a Repository within an Organization and thought it would be relevant here.

```
g = Github(token)
organization = g.get_organization("org-name")
organization.create_repo(
        name,
        allow_rebase_merge=True,
        auto_init=False,
        description=description,
        has_issues=True,
        has_projects=False,
        has_wiki=False,
        private=True,
       )
```

The full set of keyword arguments may be found here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#input

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled onto this question when trying to figure out how to create an AuthenticatedUser object. Turns out you get a NamedUser when you pass any argument to get_user, and if you give it no arguments, you get the AuthenticatedUser corresponding to the creds you used when creating the Github object.

As a minimal example, the following:

```
from github import Github
g = Github("my GitHub API token")

user = g.get_user('myname')
print user
authed = g.get_user()
print authed
```

yields

```
<github.NamedUser.NamedUser object at 0x7f95d5eeed10>
<github.AuthenticatedUser.AuthenticatedUser object at 0x7f95d5684410>
```

Once you have an AuthenticatedUser object, you can call CreateRepo as explained in the docs that you linked.

Comment: This is a better answer because it explains what the different calls return, this should be the accepted answer @ustroetz

Comment: For the create_repo() command, do you call it on the user object? Or do you create an org?

Comment: `g = Github(username, password)
gituser = g.get_user(username)
repo = gituser.create_repo(name)` is definitely not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

To create a repository, you can use GitPython. [Here is a tutorial](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#initializing-a-repository) on how to init a rep. It's as simple as:

```
import git

repo_dir = os.path.join(rw_dir, 'my-new-repo')
file_name = os.path.join(repo_dir, 'new-file')

r = git.Repo.init(repo_dir)
```

You can also use [Dulwich](https://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/) to create a repository:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
x = Repo.init("/path/to/new/repo")
```

Once you have that done, you can use [PyGithub](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v1/introduction.html) to access the repositories (or stick to the APIs provided above):

```
from github import Github

g = Github("user", "password")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print repo.name
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand you right, I first have to create a repository locally and push it then to Github? There is no way to generate a repository in Github directly with PyGithub?

Comment: There is a way using  [PyGithub.Blocking.Organization.Organization.create_repo](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/Organization.html#github.Organization.Organization.create_repo) which calls [POST /orgs/:org/repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create). I omitted that because there's no tutorials I could link for you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question:

login via token:

```
g = Github(token)

user = g.get_user()

repo = user.create_repo(repo_name)

print(repo)#To
```

login via username and password:

```
g = Github("user", "password")

user = g.get_user()

repo = user.create_repo(repo_name)

print(repo)
```

Github Enterprise with the custom hostname.

login to Enterprise GitHub which has organizations

```
g = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="token")

org = g.get_organization("org name")

repo = org.create_repo(repo_name)
```