# How to create a new repository in an organization with PyGithub

Tags: python, api, github, github-api, pygithub

How can I create a new repository in an organization with PyGithub on Github? In particular I like to know how to use the `create_repo` method?

My question is identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675121/how-to-create-a-new-repository-with-pygithub), but I would like the created repository to appear in an organization.

The solution to creating a repo without the organization level is:

```
g = Github("username", "password")
user = g.get_user()
repo = user.create_repo(full_name)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link gave me the answer: [link](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2016/07/22/pygithub-examples.html)

I thought I would update my question to let others know what the solution was.

Pretty simple:

```
from github import Github

# using username and password
g = Github("Username", "Password")
org = g.get_organization('orgName')

repo = org.create_repo("test name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to create new Repo in an organization:

using username and password establish connection to github:

```
g = Github(userName, password)
org = g.get_organization('yourOrgName')
```

If you are using Github Enterprise then use below code to login:

```
g = Github(base_url="https://your_host_name/api/v3", login_or_token="personal_access_token")
org = g.get_organization('yourOrgName')
```

create the new repository:

```
repo = org.create_repo(projectName, description = projectDescription )
```

full code to create a Repo:

```
from github import Github
import pygit2
g = Github(userName, password)
org = g.get_organization('yourOrgName')
repo = org.create_repo(projectName, description = projectDescription )
```

Clone a repo :

```
repoClone = pygit2.clone_repository(repo.git_url, 'path_where_to_clone')
```

push code to repo:

```
repoClone.remotes.set_url("origin", repo.clone_url)
index = repoClone.index
index.add_all()
index.write()
tree = index.write_tree()
oid = repoClone.create_commit('refs/heads/master', author, commiter, "init commit",tree,[repoClone.head.peel().hex])
remote = repoClone.remotes["origin"]
credentials = pygit2.UserPass(userName, password)
#if the above credentials does not work,use the below one
#credentials = pygit2.UserPass("personal_access_token", 'x-oauth-basic')
remote.credentials = credentials
callbacks=pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(credentials=credentials)
remote.push(['refs/heads/master'],callbacks=callbacks)
```

Full code to clone,create and push to a repo:

```
from github import Github
import pygit2
g = Github(userName, password)
org = g.get_organization('yourOrgName')
repo = org.create_repo(projectName, description = projectDescription )
repo.create_file("/README.md", "init commit", Readme_file)
repoClone = pygit2.clone_repository(repo.git_url, 'path_where_to_clone')
repoClone.remotes.set_url("origin", repo.clone_url)
index = repoClone.index
index.add_all()
index.write()
tree = index.write_tree()
oid = repoClone.create_commit('refs/heads/master', author, commiter, "init commit",tree,[repoClone.head.peel().hex])
remote = repoClone.remotes["origin"]
credentials = pygit2.UserPass(userName, password)
#if the above credentials does not work,use the below one
#credentials = pygit2.UserPass("personal_access_token", 'x-oauth-basic')
remote.credentials = credentials
callbacks=pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(credentials=credentials)
remote.push(['refs/heads/master'],callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Also, getting: `AttributeError: 'IndexFile' object has no attribute 'add_all'` :(

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning `create_repo_from_template` which is not yet available