# How to add a user to the github organization repository using pygithub?

Tags: python, github, repository, github-api, pygithub

I needed to add the user to the github organization repository but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Isn't this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372057/how-to-create-a-new-repository-in-an-organization-with-pygithub answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
    result = []
    organization = g.get_organization("org_name")
    team_name = 'backend'
    # TYPES OF ROLES= ["admin", "direct_member", "billing_manager"], TEAMS is ARRAY
    try:
        teams = organization.get_teams()
        for t in teams:
            if t.name == team_name:
                team = t
        result = organization.invite_user(email="user@domain.com",
                role="direct_member",
                teams=[team])
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
    if result is None:
        print(f"Successfully sent invite")
```

This is the function definition as given in Organization class for PyGithub:

```
def invite_user(
    self,
    user=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
    email=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
    role=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
    teams=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
):
    """
    :calls: `POST /orgs/{org}/invitations <http://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#members>`_
    :param user: :class:`github.NamedUser.NamedUser`
    :param email: string
    :param role: string
    :param teams: array of :class:`github.Team.Team`
    :rtype: None
    """
    assert user is github.GithubObject.NotSet or isinstance(
        user, github.NamedUser.NamedUser
    ), user
    assert email is github.GithubObject.NotSet or isinstance(email, str), email
    assert (email is github.GithubObject.NotSet) ^ (
        user is github.GithubObject.NotSet
    ), "specify only one of email or user"
    parameters = {}
    if user is not github.GithubObject.NotSet:
        parameters["invitee_id"] = user.id
    elif email is not github.GithubObject.NotSet:
        parameters["email"] = email
    if role is not github.GithubObject.NotSet:
        assert isinstance(role, str), role
        assert role in ["admin", "direct_member", "billing_manager"]
        parameters["role"] = role
    if teams is not github.GithubObject.NotSet:
        assert all(isinstance(team, github.Team.Team) for team in teams)
        parameters["team_ids"] = [t.id for t in teams]
    headers, data = self._requester.requestJsonAndCheck(
        "POST",
        f"{self.url}/invitations",
        headers={"Accept": Consts.mediaTypeOrganizationInvitationPreview},
        input=parameters,
    )
```

Some things to consider:

1. You need to have admin access to invite a user
2. You can add a user with/without the team parameter in the above code.

To get more info: [PyGithub examples](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/tree/master/doc/examples)

Answer (score -1):

This code should do the trick.

```
from github import Github
from github import Team
from github import NamedUser

access_token = "Your Personal Access Token"

g = Github(access_token)

org = g.get_organization("Your Organisation name")
org.login

# Invite user using email and role
org.invite_user(
    email='email of the invitee',
    role='direct_member')
# Other possible roles are: ["admin", "direct_member", "billing_manager"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).